# Only move groundparallax when player heading upwards in Y-axis

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

So essentially, Im making a platformjumper game. when the player collides with a platform, the player gets a forcebump in upwards in y-axis. The code down below that i got gives simulates the view following the player. It also follows the player when hes heading downwards in y-axis. I dont want that. Only want the midground, foreground and background to move down when the player is heading upwards.

**Gamescene.swift:**

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var background:SKNode!
var midground:SKNode!
var foreground:SKNode!




required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

}

override init(size: CGSize){
    super.init(size: size)

    background = createBackground()
    addChild(background)

    midground = createMidground()
    addChild(midground)

    foreground = SKNode()
    addChild(foreground)

    player = createPlayer()
    foreground.addChild(player)

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if player.position.y > 200{
        background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/10))
        midground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/4))
        foreground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y) - 200))
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the Player Position.

```
    var PlayerPosition1 = 0

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    if player.position.y > 200{
        if player.position.y > PlayerPosition1{
            background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/10))
            midground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/4))
            foreground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y) - 200))
        }
    }

    PlayerPosition1 = player.position.y
}
```

Something like that should work ..

Edit:
Ah okay .. it's not really a "lag" .. the background just moves back to the "old" position when touching the platform.. try this:

```
var PlayerMaxY = CGFloat()

    if player.position.y > 200 {
        if player.position.y > PlayerMaxY{
            PlayerMaxY = player.position.y
            background.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/10))
            midground.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)/4))
            forefround.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -((player.position.y - 200)))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but as soon as the player collides with a platform  something laggs it all upp. Not like a memory lagg, there is something with thats totally off when it launches from the plattform

Comment: Can you show the code or the things you did different from my "solution"?

Comment: I did just replace my code to yours and add the variables. other than that i have platform that gives "player.physicsbody?.velocity.dy = CGFloat(700)" when it collides with a sknode platform.

Comment: And without my "solution" its not "lagging"? If that is the case i don't know what it could be .. with each frame you check if player.position.y is higher than the previous player.position.y .. if yes = background/midground/foreground change the y position .. if no = nothing happens .. there shouldn't be any problem with that .. maybe someone else has a idea? Oh .. you declared PlayerPosition1 as CGFloat with `var PlayerPosition1 = CGFloat()`?

Comment: Yes i did. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7v7ep05yuwe5p16/SwiftJump.xcodeproj.zip?dl=0 Here is the full project. Added your code to it

Comment: You need to zip the whole folder with the other files, too (GameScene.swift for example) ..

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36803359/SwiftJump.zip here is the full original project. Replace your code with it in Gamescene

Comment: Works perfect now! Thank you so much!